# How to query DBpedia SPARQL by resource uri?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm querying DBpedia types in SPARQL (http://dbpedia.org/sparql) by resource's label

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX ru: <http://ru.dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?type ?superType WHERE { {
  ?res rdfs:label "HarryPotter"@en.
} UNION {
  ?redir dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?res .
  ?redir rdfs:label "HarryPotter"@en .
}
?res rdf:type ?type .
OPTIONAL {
  ?type rdfs:subClassOf ?superType .
}
}
```

[It works fine](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+skos%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+ru%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fru.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia2%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%3Ftype+%3FsuperType+WHERE+%7B+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fres+rdfs%3Alabel+%22HarryPotter%22%40en.%0D%0A%7D+UNION+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fredir+dbo%3AwikiPageRedirects+%3Fres+.%0D%0A++%3Fredir+rdfs%3Alabel+%22HarryPotter%22%40en+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%3Fres+rdf%3Atype+%3Ftype+.%0D%0AOPTIONAL+%7B%0D%0A++%3Ftype+rdfs%3AsubClassOf+%3FsuperType+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A+%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).

But what if I know the exact resource - http://dbpedia.org/page/Harry_Potter? I tried something like:

```
?res a :Harry_Potter.
```

But it does not work.

How to query DBpedia types and supertypes if I know the resource URI? I can't figure out which property or operator I should use (e.g., `rdfs:Resource`, `a`, etc., which do not work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
?res a :Harry_Potter.
```

It doesn't work, because this means "a resource, which is of type :Harry_Potter". It is equivalent to

```
?res rdf:type :Harry_Potter.
```

`:Harry_Potter` identifies a resource and not the type, thus it should be used in place of `?res`.

Also I think you mean `Harry_Potter_(character)`, because that is the actual identifier and not redirect.

You query would be as simple as

```
SELECT ?type ?superType WHERE 
{ 
  # give me ?type of the resource
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter_(character)> rdf:type ?type .

  # give me ?superTypes of ?type
  OPTIONAL {
   ?type rdfs:subClassOf ?superType .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the URI as the subject in there WHERE conditions.

```
SELECT ?title, ?releaseDate
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Super_Mario_Bros._3> dbp:title  ?title .
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Super_Mario_Bros._3> dbo:releaseDate ?releaseDate .
}
```